# SQL Join: Performing Join on a table by selecting the last record

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to figure out how to perform a Join with another table based on the most recent row in the other table. Say I have three tables.

- Customer: Customer Details
- CustomerReport: A customer could have multiple reports. The recent report will be the highest `reportId`
- ReportStatus: Detailed status of the report

Customer Table

```sql
Id  Name
1   ABC
2   DEF
3   GHI
4   XYZ
```

CustomerReport Table

```sql
customerId  reportId
1           10
1           11
1           12
2           21
2           22
3           30
3           31
4           40
4           41
```

ReportStatus Table

```sql
reportId timestamp              status
10       2024-01-14 00:11:47    false
11       2024-01-15 00:11:47    false
12       2024-01-24 00:11:47    true
21       2024-01-14 00:11:47    false
22       2024-01-16 00:11:47    false
30       2024-01-16 00:11:47    false
31       2024-01-16 00:11:47    false
40                              false
41                              false
```

For all the customers, I want to use their latest reportId (largest value) and find if the report was filed before 2024-01-24. I want to ignore `null` exportedAt values as well.

So for the above records, I am looking at something like

```sql
CustomerId  Name    ReportId TimeStamp              Status
2           DEF     22       2024-01-16 00:11:47    false
3           GHI     31       2024-01-16 00:11:47    false
```

I tried something like the below. But this doesn't filter out the latest `reportId`

```sql
SELECT C.id,
    C.Name
    CR.reportId,
    RS.timestamp,
    RS.status
FROM customer C 
    JOIN CustomerReport CR ON (C.id=CR.customerId) 
    JOIN ReportStatus RS ON CR.reportId=RS.reportId 
WHERE RS.timestamp<'2024-01-24'
LIMIT 20;
```

I am trying to see how to perform a join with the `ReportStatus` table to this query

```
SELECT C.id,
    C.Name
    CR.reportId
FROM customer C 
    JOIN CustomerReport CR ON (C.id=CR.customerId) 
ORDER BY CR.reportId DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: In general, ID columns created with sequences should serve only as row identifiers and should carry no additional semantic load, including any temporal significance.

Comment: This is just an example schema of a bigger table that I don't have control on

Comment: Remember: SQL tables do not have any concept of "last" or "most recent". In fact, databases are completely free to re-order records stored on disk behind the scenes, and some systems will do this, eg to take advantage of tiered storage. You MUST be able to describe this based on data actually stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Partition by id, and use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to number each id's most recent row as 1.

```
SELECT id, name, reportId, timestamp, status,
       case when timestamp < '2024-01-24 00:00:00' then FALSE else TRUE end
FROM (
  SELECT C.id,
      C.Name,
      CR.reportId,
      RS.timestamp,
      RS.status,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.id ORDER BY RS.timestamp DESC) RN
  FROM customer C 
      JOIN CustomerReport CR ON (C.id=CR.customerId) 
      JOIN ReportStatus RS ON CR.reportId=RS.reportId 
) dt
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to accommodate for `null` in my timestamp.

Comment: Do you mind explain the query and how this works?

Comment: I want to completely ignore Customer Id 1 in the above example.